# How to make a Muiv5 TreeView with Checkbox for an array of objects?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, treeview

I am using muiv5 treeview component to build a treeview dropdown. The component doesn't have checkbox support for selection/deselection but after bit of searching I was able to find a kind of similar solution but the data that needs to be passed to tree view is an object and it has a parent node. I don't need a parent node. Basically my structure is an array of objects and not an object.
Here is a link to codesandbox project [Click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/edeyu?file=/src/sampleData.tsx)

The rich object is

```js
const data: RenderTree = {
  id: 'root',
  name: 'Parent',
  children: [
    {
      id: '1',
      name: 'Child - 1',
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      name: 'Child - 3',
      children: [
        {
          id: '4',
          name: 'Child - 4',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
```

but my data is

```js
const data = [
    {
      id: '1',
      name: 'Child - 1',
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      name: 'Child - 3',
      children: [
        {
          id: '4',
          name: 'Child - 4',
        },
      ],
    },
],
```

I don't want a root parent node to display

Comment: Why don't you just update the object in the example you showed and then work your way backwards? Or if you don't intend to use the recursion in the example, then why not take the object idea and apply it to a base tree view sample from MUI? All you're really doing is updating the label on the TreeItem.

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for same solution but didn't find it, so I created one.

Please note that for the de-selecting you should add the parent node.

Please look on my working example: [Working example using MUI library](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-euclid-ywcjxt?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Do you know how to add indeterminate status when only parts of children are checked.

Comment: Yes, I added the logic to the example, please look on the Checkbox component.


`indeterminate={!selectedNodes.includes(nodes.id) && getAllChild(nodes.id) .slice(getAllChild(nodes.id).indexOf(nodes.id) + 1).some((n) => selectedNodes.includes(n))}`